# Redundancy in the description of transfinite induction

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am wondering if there is redundancy in the description of transfinite induction:

Let $A \subseteq \lambda$, where $\lambda$ is an ordinal. If (1) $\boldsymbol{0} \in A$; (2) for all ordinals $\beta$, if $\beta \subseteq A$, then $\beta \in A$; then $A = \lambda$.

I am wondering if (1) is redundant. With only (2), as $\boldsymbol{0} = \emptyset \subseteq A$ is trivially true, we have $\boldsymbol{0} \in A$. Thus, (1) is included in (2). Why do we still need (1)?

Comment: You're right; (1) is redundant. It's correctly omitted by lots of authors; presumably the authors of the definition you quoted are (like too many other people) uncomfortable with the empty set.  Incidentally, in (2), "for all ordinals $\beta$" should be "for all ordinals $\beta\in\lambda$.

Comment: It's probably the same reason that people often include $P(0)$ in the statement of strong induction: namely, often the $n=0$ case must be dealt with separately anyway.